# Better alternative for comparing two generics in my class.

Tags: java, class, generics

I need help guys.
Is there any better version for comparing two generics in this class "TreeBag"?

My current solution is doing this:

```
public class TreeBag<T> implements Bag<T>, Comparator<T> {
.
.
.
    @Override 
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(o1.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(o2.toString());
        if (temp < 0)
            return -1;
        else if (temp > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

That`s my current solution. But I do thing that's a very unsightly solution. 
Is there any better solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think an arbitrary `T` `toString` will return something that can be parsed to an `int`?

Comment: What do you want to compare by?

Comment: if you compare `ints` you can do `return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(...),Integer.parseInt(...));`

Comment: Your type is not constrained properly. ``<T extends Comparator>``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TreeBag` should not try to *be* a comparator, it should *have* a comparator:

```
 public class TreeBag<T> implements Bag<T> {
    private final Comparator<? super T> comparator;

    public TreeBag(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator, "comparator");
    }

    /// and somewhere 
   void somewhere() {
       T o1 = ....;
       T o2 = ....;

      int rc = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
      if (rc < 0) {
      } else if (rc > 0) {
      } else {
      }  
   }
}
```

A `TreeBag<String>` would then for example be created with `new TreeBag<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`.

A `TreeBag<Integer>` would then be created with `new TreeBag<Integer>(Comparator.naturalOrder());`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do proper comparison Comparator MUST know what should be compared.

Several ways to improve your design:

1. Use `<T extends Comparable>` and use `o1.compareTo(o2)`
2. Use `<T extends YourDomainObject>` and write specific logic for `YourDomainObject` in `compare` method
3. Make `TreeBag` abstract and write specific logic for `YourDomainObject` in `compare` method of concrete class: `MyTreeBag extends TreeBag<YourDomainObject> { ...`
4. Provide Comparator for TreeBag
5. And so on